# Deriving a constant in a probability mass function

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Let $Y_1, \ldots , Y_n$ be a random sample from a zero-truncated Poisson distribution with probability
>   mass function:
>
> $$p_Y (y\mid λ) = k\frac{λ^ye^{-λ}}{y!},$$
>   $k > 0, λ > 0, y = 1, 2, \ldots ,$
>   where $k$ is an unknown constant.

I know that the sum of a probability mass function is $1$, but I do not know how to use this information to find $k$.

Comment: Did you mean that to be $e^{-y}$ or $e^{-\lambda}$?

Comment: I've changed it now! Thank you for noticing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p$ is a probability mass function
$$1
=\sum _{y=1}^\infty k\frac{λ^ye^{-\lambda}}{y!}
=ke^{-\lambda}\sum _{y=1}^\infty\frac{λ^y}{y!} 
=ke^{-\lambda}(e^{\lambda}-1).
$$

Comment: This is excellent, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know that $\displaystyle \sum_{y=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^y}{y!} = e^\lambda,$ then the form of the probability mass function of the Poisson distribution will tell you that.

It follows that $\displaystyle\sum_{y=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^y}{y!} = e^\lambda - 1.$